# PHP Static functions don't work when directory changes?

Tags: php

I have a class that looks like this:

utils/Result.php

```
<?php

class Result
{
    public static function ok()
    {
        echo "OK";
    }   
}
```

If I create the following script

./sandbox.php

```
<?php

require_once("utils/Result.php");

print_r(Result::ok());
```

And run it with `php sandbox.php` it works fine. But if I do the following: `cd test && php ../sandbox.php` it gives me the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Result::ok() in /mnt/hgfs/leapback/sandbox.php on line 5
```

Now, realize that the require statement seems to be working. If I add a property to the Result class, and use print_r on an instance of it, it looks right. But the static methods disappear. I'm very confused. I'm running php 5.2.6.

Comment: If you replace your require_once statement with `require_once dirname(FILE) . '/utils/Result.php'` - What happens?

Comment: Uhh, damnit, comment formatting... that's supposed to be underscore underscore FILE underscore underscore

Comment: What happen if you remove the "public static"?

Comment: @jason: You can use back-ticks in comments, too: `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @soulmerge: If you hadn't noticed, I did use backticks. Hence the monospace font, etc.

Comment: @inakiabt: You'd throw a `E_STRICT` notice in PHP 5, and the method would still be public.

Comment: @jason - it works - ok... that forces the require to work as if I was in the other directory, but it's supposed to work either way, right? Shouldn't it fail if there's no result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a 'utils/Result.php' file in the directory you have changed to (`test`)? If yes, it will be included instead of the original file.

Comment: No. I just made a new directory to be certain. It still happens.

Comment: Dang... You're all right. I had "include_path" creep because I idiotically set the php.ini path to globally include another project's code. Thanks guys